# Need to convert PCX graphic to binary

Tags: javascript, graphic, pcx

I have an application that requires I convert a PCX graphic to binary. There is very little info on the internet on how to do this. I can accomplish this with canvas.toDataURL using JS but only for PNG and JPEG graphic files. This is not for a SQL database as I think you can do it there. Any help would be appreciated, even if it involves using an app to get me there.

Comment: What do you mean "convert to binary"? PCX files are binary surely - they aren't ASCII text. Or do you mean you want to "binarize" the image so it is black and white?

Comment: "Very little on the Internet" -- all it needs is a good PCX file format description. It's a positively *ancient* format, and surely there are heaps of web sites with good info? From memory: it's an extremely basic RLE encoding scheme, using the value of 192 as pivot.

Comment: I'm using a positively ancient device that communicates only via serial port and thus can only receive an image as a PCX graphic 8 bit 256 color indexed and as binary or text data that can be uploaded serially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea what you mean by your question, but I presume that if you can do whatever it is that you want with a JPEG file but can't do that with a PCX file, it would help if you could convert your PCX to a JPEG.

So I would suggest you use "convert" from ImageMagick ([here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php))

```
convert image.pcx image.jpg
```

Here is a text file:

```
This is the first line
You can read me, con't you?
Yes, it's because I am text
```

Here is a binary file:

```
<FF><D8><FF><E0>^@^PJFIF^@^A^A^A^@^A^@^A^@^@<FF><DB>^@C^@^C^B^B^B^B^B^C^B^B^B^C^C^C^C^D
^L^R^S^R^P^S^O^P^P^P<FF><DB>^@C^A^C^C^C^D^C^D^H^D^D^H^P^K       ^K^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P<FF><C0>^@^Q^H^A<90>^@<C8>^C^A"^@^B^Q^A^C^Q^A<FF><C4>^@^]^@^@^@^G^A^A^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^B^C
^D^E^F^G^H^A     <FF><C4>^@8^P^@^A^C^C^C^B^E^B^D^F^C^@^B^C^@^@^A^B^C^Q^@^D!^E^R1^FA^G^S"Qaq<81>^T2<91><A1>^H^U#B<B1><D1>R<C1><E1>^V<F0>3br<FF><C4>^@^Z^A^@^B^C^A^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^B^C^A^D^E^@^F<FF><C4>^@/^Q^@^B^B^A^D^A^C^
```

Comment: To clarify I need the PCX image as binary (text) so it can be stored or sent as serial data. It needs to remain as a PCX image.

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't make sense. If a file is text, its is letters nd normal characters that humans can read. On Windows you can do "TYPE FILE" and it will look ok, or on Unix you can do "more file" and it will look ok. If it is binary, it will be gobbledegook if you run either of those commands. It can't be both text and binary. It is one or the other.

Comment: Mea culpa. I am slipping on a semantic slippery slope. It is your second example... a binary conversion expressed as text gobblygoop. How do I turn the PCX into the binary file? Is it as simple as viewing the graphic as a .txt file... I mean binary text file... I mean gobbleygoop...my head is gonna explode : )

Comment: @hillcreative There's no such thing... if you dump any pcx file into notepad you _get_ that gobbledegook. The file is already like that; there's nothing to convert. It's just the file's bytes (mis)interpreted as being text.